# Jquery UI drag and drop needs to update Class.Priority in code behind when moved

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a working example of a drag-able list of items. This works absolutely perfect except that I need the movement of these items to reflect in an item array behind the scenes. Basically I am using an `ASP:Repeater` object to create a mock up of this accompanying jsfiddle. ->
http://jsfiddle.net/no3z85dk/

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSearchResults" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul id="sortable">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="ui-state-default" />
        <div class="lightShadowBox">
            <asp:Label ID="Description" runat="server" Visible="false" Text=<%# Eval("Description") %>></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Priority" runat="server" Visible="false" Text=<%# Eval("Priority") %>></asp:Label>
        </div>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Right now the items are being displayed in Priority order. For instance, they start out listing in ascending order like:

**Priority | Type**

1 Cat

2 Dog

3 Turtle

4 Pig

**5 Fish**

If the user drags 5 up to 2's slot, I would need it to appear like this:

**Priority | Type**

1         Cat

**2         Fish**

3         Dog

4         Turtle

5         Pig

In the end I basically just need to update the `Priority` field through the code behind whenever the user drags the item to a new location. Is this even possible with this method of click/drag?

Also, here is the class being updated to reflect these changes:

```
public class Object
{
    private string _description;
    private string _priority;

    public Object(string description, string priority )
    {
        Description = description;
        Priority = priority;
    }
    public Object() { }

    public string Description { get { return _description; } set { _description = value; } }
    public string Priority { get { return _priority; } set { _priority = value; } }
}
```

This item is declared as a static `Object`.

```
public partial class MyApp : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    #region Declarations
    public Boolean isDebugMode = Convert.ToBoolean(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["isDebugMode"]);
    static Object sessionObject = new Object();
    #endregion

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for some callback that happens on drag-drop? Where is the item array persisted?

Comment: @Mrchief More less I think I am. The class is declared as a static variable.

Comment: So you're looking at tapping into [drag stop](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop) event. You can then do a callback to update the positions on server.